# Use StringBuilder or String in the following case?

Tags: java

```
String address=null;
String body = "";
String date = "";

for(int i = 0; somecondition; i++)
{    
    body = cursor.getBody(i);
   //and so on all strings get changed

//REST OF THE CODE
}
```

This loops for arround 500 times so what should I use?

Comment: If you are trying to build a string, I would recommend `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Want to assign value then use String type.

Comment: Please reread your example code as several things don't make sense. It will also help for you to better explain the situation.

Comment: Example makes no sense. Every loop iteration does the same thing, without looking at `i`. There is no String being built/concatenated. What is the question?

Comment: actually i an assigning new value each time..so what should i use??

Comment: its an i insted of 1..updated my code

Comment: I can't see the point of this, since by the end of the loop `body`, `address`, etc. will just have the same value as it did right before the loop ended... So why is the loop there in the first place? (assuming `cursor.getBody(i)` doesn't change the state of the your program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that nothing changes in the String you are just reassigning it, use a String.  StringBuilder is used when you want to build up a String in pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just assigning some string to the variable, just use String instead of StringBuilder. StringBuilder as its name suggest, is used for building a new string where concatenation or manipulation is desired.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't build any String, just going assign values. In that case you can use `String`